# VsCode - Weird JSX prop autocomplete behavior

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, jsx, intellisense

When writing JSX props in typescript, this is what it normally looks like for me, works as expected:

[image]

However, if I let VsCode autocomplete the style (or another) tag like this:

[image]

then I get into a weird mode where the space between the braces has a gray background:

[image]

In this mode, autocomplete does not work (you can see that the first line of the popup is not highlighted). Pressing return produces a newline instead of accepting the first suggestion.
When adding new lines, it looks like this:

[image]

My questions are:

1. What is this strange mode supposed to do?
2. Is this intended or a bug?
3. What is it called?
4. Can I disable it?

VsCode 1.75.0 on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had this similar behavior that was bothering me.

> What is this strange mode supposed to do?

They wanted suggestions to behave like snippets, that's why there is this little placeholder for the caret where you can quickly go by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

> Is this intended or a bug?

It is intended by default by VS Code as the configuration `editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions` default is set to `true`

> What is it called?

`snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions` as the configuration states.

> Can I disable it?

You can by setting the `editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions` to `false`.

Comment: I just tried turning the setting off and it seems like it worked! Thanks so much!